# Modelling a mess of lines for an architectural building?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I have this architectural model to build and before I leap into it, I was wondering if you had any great ideas to make the random lines of this appear over the outer walls?

[image: reference image]

http://www.nemesistudio.it/en/projects/type/culture/item/714-italy-pavilion-expo-2015-milan.html

It will be for a low poly model (ie in a game environment), so I was thinking of modelling the basic shape of the walls (eg a curved box basically) and then modelling the main lines on top (with Shrinkwrap) but making the smaller lines as a transparent png. Just keeping in mind I'm trying to make this as low in poly count as possible.

Any better ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an addon that comes to mind which is quite popular, [by-gen](https://curtisjamesholt.gumroad.com/l/BY-GEN) by Curtis Holt, they also put up a bunch of resources about it on their youtube channel

Comment: Neither low poly nor very clean so it's not an answer, but maybe this would be of some help to you in some way: https://i.imgur.com/FWqJnS5.png The 'Bounce Spline' from 'Add Curve: Extra Objects' addon "fills" the volume of the selected object with a randomized curve. To limit it to the outer walls, created a very thin shell with a solidify modifier on a copy of my building and used that to create the Spline. Then, shrinkwrapped that onto the original building with a little offset. Two separate splines, one for thick lines and one for thin, with these settings: https://i.imgur.com/NjczIEo.png

Answer (score 3):

Addon - Add Curve Extra Object

Curve -Knots - Bounce Spline

[image]

Edit:

Oh lol, Kuboå answer the same :D